# $_POST via cURL not working

Tags: php, api, post, curl

Im trying my hand at using curl to post some data, I am not reciving my post content and can not find the source of the problem

curl.php

```
<?php 

$data = array("user_email" => "22" , "pass" => "22" ); 
$string = http_build_query($data);


$ch = curl_init("http://localhost:8888/290_project/test.php"); //this is where post data goes too, also starts curl
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch) //ends curl
?>
```

test.php

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['user_email'], $_POST['pass'])) {

$name = $_POST['user_email'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];

echo $name;
echo $pass;

} else {
echo "error";
} ?>
```

Every time I get my error response meaning the post data is not going through. I have tried everything I could think of to trouble shoot;I must be over looking something I am simply not yet familiar with?

Comment: Try to specify the port: `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_PORT, 8888);`

Comment: send $data instead of $string

Comment: No luck with the previous comments, used together or independently.

Comment: FYI: I am following this video for instruction: youtube.com/watch?v=2YdBrkDdn0M

Comment: @Vinie you were proposing this correct? curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $string);

Comment: @n-dru your code used would look like this right?  $ch = curl_init("http://localhost:8888/290_project/test.php"); //this is where post data goes too, also starts curl
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_PORT, 8888);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

Comment: The network tab in my developer console shows no interaction with curl.php

Comment: Does cURL have to be installed, like via command line?

Comment: yes curl should be enabled in apache

Comment: Checked for curl in the terminal, got libcurl 7.28.1 so it is installed.

Comment: phpinfo() also shows it as enabled.

Comment: if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
} use this and see what error is coming

Comment: No error was detected, I get no response checking for false or true (and echoing a string saying "true")

Comment: Any working examples of using curl to post like I want? I have tried a few now with no luck.

Answer (score 2):

Please set CURLOPT_URL to http://localhost:8888.....

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost:8888/290_project/test.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_exec($ch);

if(!curl_errno($ch)){ 
$info = curl_getinfo($ch); 
} else { 
echo  'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch); 
} 
curl_close($ch) //ends curl
?>
```

With curl_getinfo() - Gets information about the last transfer. 
For more detail read below link:- http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php

I have edited the answer, The reason for error is not curl.

```
http_build_query($data, '', '&');
```

Comment: syntax error ... if(isset($_POST['user_email'], $_POST['pass'])) And please check what you get in $_POST key

Answer (score 0):

Following is working example. Please try this.

```
$postData = array(
        'user_name' => 'abcd',
        'password' => 'asdfghj',
        'redirect' => 'yes',
        'user_login' => '1'
    );
$url='http://localhost:8888/290_project/test.php';
$ch = curl_init();
//Set the URL to work with
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
// ENABLE HTTP POST
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
//Set the post parameters
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
//execute the request
$store = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($store);
curl_close($ch)
```

Answer (score -1):

You have an error in your php code:

edit:

```
if(isset($_POST['user_email'], $_POST['pass'])) {
```

to:

```
if(isset($_POST['user_email']) && isset($_POST['pass'])) {
```

Comment: `isset(...)` can accept multiple values. It will evaluate from left to right and  will return false on the first parameter that is not found